# Is there an SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there an SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition? I have read there is, but I only see 2008 R1 Developer on Microsoft's website and can't find where to get it. If someone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. I tried Microsoft's sales, but the person I talked to didn't seem to know. If I can't get it now I have to go back to the Express version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is not yet available. You can buy the license from Microsoft Volumne Licensing, but you have to purchase at least 5, which I'm not doing.

Answer (score 2):

> File Name:
>   en_sql_server_2008_r2_developer_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_522665.iso Date Published (UTC): 5/3/2010 9:45:43
>   AM    Last Updated (UTC): 5/3/2010
>   9:45:43 AM SHA1:
>   10B990A86961D84C4D7D5E8C3A4C67F0D0456E63
>     ISO/CRC: 272D2E95 Available to
>   Levels: VS Pro with MSDN Premium
>   (Empower); Developer AA; Designer AA;
>   VS Pro with MSDN (Retail); VS Premium
>   with MSDN (MPN); VS Pro with MSDN
>   Premium (MPN); MSDN Universal (VL);
>   BizSpark Admin; BizSpark; VS Test Pro
>   with MSDN (VL); VS Ultimate with MSDN
>   (VL); VS Premium with MSDN (VL); VS
>   Pro with MSDN (VL); VS Test Pro with
>   MSDN (Retail); VS Premium with MSDN
>   (Retail); VS Ultimate with MSDN
>   (Retail);

These is one, it's located under SQL Server 2008 R2 on MSDN.

Comment: I can't find where you can purchase the Developer edition on MSDN. I don't have an MSDN subscription if you are assuming I have one.

Comment: Yes I have an MSDN subscription :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be a $50 Developer Edition of SQL SErver 2008 R2 according to this article here:

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server-2005-express/sql-server-2008-r2-editions.aspx

Marc